# Using the Node SDK vs HTTP APIs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am interesting to hear peoples opinions on using the `HTTP` APIs auto built by the REST server VS using the NPM module `require('composer-client')`.

Interested to hear in what cases you would decide to use each type to interact with the chain - especially if you are building a node app.

Thanks!
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

I primarily use the composer-client tools to set up demos which I can log into as different users/cards and switch between them. Otherwise I would need a rest-server for each card.